# Disable system sound (ding) for disabled forms

Tags: c#

I have a form which can be set to .Enabled = false;. The client still might click on it by accident which can turn out to be very annoying since every time you click on it you will get this ding sound. I was wondering whether it's possible to disable that or not.

Comment: One way around might be disabling all the controls inside the Form instead of the form itself.

Comment: I just don't want the user to be able to move the form by accident and this seemed to be the easiest way.

Comment: Are you talking about PC Speaker/Beeper sound?

Comment: Just curious, why shouldn't the user move the form?

Comment: What you mean "move the form"? Drag the window with the mouse?

Comment: Yes, drag the form to a different location. And the reason it shouldn't move is because the user decided to put the form exactly there. And no this is not a matter of bad UI design because there is a reason the form should stay there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `Enable` to false, you can hide the whole title bar with those two lines of code:

```
this.Text = "";
this.ControlBox = false;
```

This will result in user not being able to move the window, you can store the original title then restore it later if you want.

Comment: Haven't thought about that, sounds to be the best idea so far.

Comment: Cheers.. if you want the title to appear even when "disabled", you can add panel with Dock set to Top with the proper text.

Answer (score 0):

You could register to the Move event for the form and restore its location to wherever you want it to be (it should zero in to the top left corner IIRC).

Comment: Preventing form movement is frowned upon and considered bad UI design anyway (thought it should be noted)

Comment: General speaking yes but not in this case since the user wants the form to stay at the location he decided to put it. Since he might move it by accident which he doesn't want to it should not be movable. @alex You're right I could do this but still there should be a way to disable these annoying sounds. If not I guess I will use the move event.